# polymorphism and action bubbling in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, polymorphism, hierarchy, abstract-syntax-tree, redux

I'm using Redux(+React) to make operate on hierarchical structures and I have two questions:

1. how to implement polymorphism in Redux?
2. how to make "action bubbling"

My questions expressed more precisely:

1. .

I'm making structural code editor in React, using Redux. By structural editor I mean that I have tree structure with nodes in it and my app is supposed to operate on AST rather than plain text.

These nodes can have various types (because it's editor for editing CSS files, these types are for example: "rule", "declaration", "property", "value", but it's more important that they do have some type at all). So there are objects in JS which have property `type` and its `type` determines its... type ;)

So assume that I have node like this:

```
{
    type: 'property', 
    id: 4, 
    rule: '.content > ul > li', 
    children: [...blah blah......]
}
```

And I would like to be able write something like that:

`store.dispatch({type: 'click', nodeId: 4})`

for click. But I would expect that clicking on node of type `rule` would have other effect than clicking on node of type `property`. Polymorphism (but I would like to have ONE react component `<Node />` to prevent code duplication).

I know I can achieve that either by switch/case or making my own sub-functions (I mean to delegate action to functions), but I don't want reinvent the the wheel. I think that support of polymorphism would be useful to many applications, not only mine.

So - how to achieve polymorphism in Redux?

2.,
Second question about action bubbling. Because I got tree structure for example such like this one:

```
{
    type: 'rule',
    rule: 'body div',
    id: 1,
    children: [
         {
              type: 'declaration',
              id: 2,
              children: [
                    {type: 'property', name: 'display', id: 3},
                    {type: 'value', value: 'block', id: 4},
              ]
         } 
    ]
}
```

And I have appropriate React components that render that structure (I have dumb function-based stateless React 0.14 components, so I don't think components' code is very important right now). Anyway I got `<Node/>` component that represents single AST node.

I would like that user could click on for example on node at id=3 ( `{type: 'property', name: 'display', id: 3},`) and action would automatically "bubble" to node's parents (in this case to declaration node at id=2  and to rule node at id=1).

As far I know there is no "action bubbling" in Redux. Maybe it should be? Or maybe what I would like to achieve could be made by other means? (by "action bubbling" I mean something similar to "event bubbling" in JavaScript events in browser, only I would like `redux actions` to bubble and I do NOT want DOM events to bubble (this is completely other thing). I would like to redux action to bubble. When I wrote "bubbling" I ment overall design pattern rather than implementation.

And these were my two questions :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great question, based on what I understood of redux the reducers violate the Open Closed and the Single Responsibility principles because they on the same reducer you can handle multiple events and if you want to add an other handler you need to change the reducer code...

```
// This is kind of the standard approach 
// It has a big switch case that knows how to handle many actions (single responsibility violation).
// The more actions you have the bigger this function becomes, to handle an other even you need to change the reducer (open closed violation). 
export default function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_ENTRIES':
    return setEntries(state, action.payload);
  case 'NEXT':
    return next(state);
  case 'VOTE':
    return vote(state, action.payload)
  }

  // return the current state if the action you try to use dont exist
  return state;
}
```

In the case above the actions will be like `{type: 'VOTE', payload: {...}}`... I personally don't like that approach because it is not flexible and I think we can do much better by using **polymorphism** below is an example of a polymorphic reducer that is much more flexible:

```
// This is a polymorphic aprorach that conforms to all SOLID principles
// This is much simpler and will raise an error if the action does not exist
export default function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  return action.handler(state, action.payload);
}
```

On the case above the actions will look like `{handler: vote, payload: {...}}` this approach is much more flexible, you could even create disposable a `{handler: (state) => { ... }}` with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Polymorphism

I think you already hit on the answer when you mentioned creating small reusable functions. I don't agree that polymorphism would be a superior alternative. Redux is all about functional programming, not gargantuan inheritance trees.

2. Action bubbling.

Remember that in Redux/Flux your store is your single source of truth. Your view components (i.e. React elements) derive their data from the store. Information (i.e. props) flows top-down from your root element onto its children and then onto to its children, etc.

Thus all your action needs to do is update your store. The rest takes care of itself. Information bubbles, but not directly from the child to the parent. Instead it goes from the child to the store (via an action) and only then to the parent.

Comment: 1. polymorphism is not about inheritance but "is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types". ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)  ). For example Redux reducers are polymorphic because one reducer function is supposed to react differently depending on action type :)

Comment: 2. I had problems in "flows top-down" approach because after every action whole tree was rerendered and app was terrible slow. Maybe I was doing it wrong, but now I connect Redux to React by myself (without official bindings) and instead of "flow top-down" I put every stateless element in smart stateful container that listens to changes of interesting fragment of state and rerender its dumb stateless child.